# Strange letter puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay

What has $4$ letters, sometimes $9$ letters, always $6$ letters and never $5$ letters. How?

> Hint: $4$ letters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well; for a start:

> The *word* "what" itself has four letters, the word "sometimes" has nine, the word "always" has six letters and the word "never" has five. So...
>
>  *What has $4$ letters, sometimes $9$ letters, always $6$ letters and never $5$ letters. How?* **$3$ letters!**
>
>  * worth noting that this was entirely [@WAF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/53367/waf) in the comments.

Comment: You got the trick, but how?

Comment: Think literally

Comment: Maybe just apply the same rule to the bold word as well.

Comment: @WAF good thought — why didn't I think of that? If it's correct, I owe you.

Comment: Heh. It's all yours! Always happy to collaborate.

Answer (score 3):

> I kind of second Hugh's answer, but with a slight addition. What's in the question's body isn't really a question. It's a statement. *What* has 4 letters, *sometimes* 9 letters, *always* 6 letters and *never* 5 letters. It's just a count of the number of letters in each word succeeding the comma. This is like a guide/legend to answer the real question.

The real question

> lies in the title ==> *But, how is **this** possible?*

The answer:

> Taking the prototype in the statement given above... **this** has **4** letters. That is how THIS is possible. In other words... the answer to **How is THIS possible?**

Comment: Ha, lol. I should havs got that. Well done

Comment: Ummm... It was actually about "How"...
A really good conclusion but the fact that the title wasn't allowing me less than 15 characters. I am sorry

Comment: "How?" _is_ a question. it implies **How about "how"?**

Comment: I get it now @MohammadZuhairKhan. I took the title in the literal way.. good one though